# Is it safe to use math.Round instead of this Modf/Ceil/Floor combo

Tags: go

I'm in the progress of converting [some Go code](https://github.com/boombuler/barcode/blob/master/qr/versioninfo.go#L278) to C# and am wondering if the following piece of code:

```golang
_, x := math.Modf(frac)
if x >= 0.5 {
    frac = math.Ceil(frac)
} else {
    frac = math.Floor(frac)
}
```

would be any different to this:

```golang
frac = math.Round(frac)
```

I know rounding can sometimes be tricky so I wonder if the first snippit acts as a workaround for something.

Comment: No, it is not safe. The two snippets evaluate to different values for the input  -1.1.

Comment: You're right, didn't think about that, however in the code I'm porting, the `frac` value is always positive, so it's probably safe to use the C# `Math.Round` equivalent.